# html php get dom table - can't extract table data

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to extract the two tables at http://www.lolking.net/now/euw/tallmangreen using Get HTML DOM, however I can't seem to string the correct data together to pull the information, I am only getting what's on the following web page: http://burnsy.co.uk/lol/example/example_basic_selector.php

Could you please assist in what I am doing wrong? The following PHP code is in use

```
    <?php
// example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.lolking.net/now/euw/tallmangreen/');

// find all link
//foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
//    echo $e->href . '<br>';

// find all image
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';

// find all image with full tag
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';

// find all div tags with id=gbar
foreach($html->find('div#gbar') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

// find all span tags with class=gb1
foreach($html->find('span.gb1') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';

// find table - MY EDIT
foreach($html->find('table.purple-team lknow-team-table td') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

// find all td tags with attribite align=center
foreach($html->find('td[align=center]') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

// extract text from table
echo $html->find('td[align="center"]', 1)->plaintext.'<br><hr>';

// extract text from HTML
echo $html->plaintext;
?>
```

Comment: You are not parsing all contents. So you don't get the expected output..

Comment: I think it's because the website waits to pull the table data then refreshes.. is there a way of getting the server to pause to wait for the refresh then output the data?

Answer (score 0):

the selector that you use is not correct. this statement will not check for the 2 classes on the element table

```
foreach($html->find('table.purple-team lknow-team-table td') as $e)
```

**Correct**

```
foreach($html->find('table[class=purple-team lknow-team-table] td') as $e)
```

I checked this code without the td tag at the end and got the whole table back.

Comment: Thanks, I have just updated my code, but the table still isn't pulling back. http://burnsy.co.uk/lol/example/example_basic_selector.php

    // find table - My EDIT
foreach($html->find('table[class=purple-team lknow-team-table] td') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';

Is my echo wrong?

Comment: can you link which simple_html_dom.php file you are using? i was using Website: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ and it works correct i get all the td's that are on the html page you provided.

Comment: That is the html DOM that I am using. I can give you FTP access to the particular folder if you're willing to help?